# Why would Django not migrate an app to create tables in Mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.8

Using Ubuntu 14.10, Python 2.7 and MySQL

I am trying to makemigrations and syncdb for Django 1.8,

I have included the app in my INSTALLED_APPS settings, created the DB in MySQL and of course put Models into the app.

When I go to

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

or

```
$ python manage.py migrate polls
```

I am told that nothing needs to be migrated, my database stays the same (with the basic Django tables)

## EDIT Apps Folder structure:

```
    polls
├── admin.py
├── admin.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── migrations
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── models.py
├── models.pyc
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

Polls.models as requested.

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForiegnKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Is there a known issue or fix for this?

Comment: Please check that you have added the app in the Installed_apps in settings

Comment: Hi @Arun I have checked that, all of my settings are configured as they should. I am using Django 1.8 if that helps?

Comment: Could you add your app's folder structure to the question? Eg: `tree polls/`

Comment: May be you  got mistake in polls.models? Post your models pls

Comment: @avs Amended please see above.

Comment: How do you determine that the database stays the same? Maybe you are looking in the wrong place...

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini could you clarify a little? I have created the DB in Mysql and named it. Then I provided the name in the settings.py to join the two. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "ForiegnKey" is typo?

Comment: @avs you are awesome, how I did not spot that I will never know.  Thank you

Comment: @Akseone Suggest you use an editor that works well with Python; for example, spyder - then those typos are highlighted for you & easy to see.